# Is there any function in Pandas to unstack column values into separate columns with multiple identifying columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2qT4.png

| Market | LoanID | Segment | LoanTerm | Field | FieldValue | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aus | AMID11 | Sales | 6 | End AR | 1 | Jan |
| Aus | AMID11 | Sales | 6 | End AR | 1 | Feb |
| Aus | AMID11 | Sales | 6 | End AR | 1 | Mar |
| Aus | AMID12 | Marketing | 12 | End AR | 0 | Jan |
| Aus | AMID12 | Marketing | 12 | End AR | 1 | Feb |
| Aus | AMID12 | Marketing | 12 | End AR | 1 | Mar |
| Aus | AMID11 | Sales | 6 | IntRate | 15.7% | Jan |
| Aus | AMID11 | Sales | 6 | IntRate | 16.7% | Feb |
| Aus | AMID11 | Sales | 6 | IntRate | 15.7% | March |
| Aus | AMID12 | Marketing | 12 | IntRate | - | Jan |
| Aus | AMID12 | Marketing | 12 | IntRate | 15.7% | Feb |
| Aus | AMID12 | Marketing | 12 | IntRate | 16.7% | Mar |

I want my output to be something like this -https://i.stack.imgur.com/98U38.png

| Market | LoanID | Segment | LoanTerm | Month | End AR | IntRate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aus | AMID11 | Sales | 6 | Jan | 1 | 15.7% |
| Aus | AMID11 | Sales | 6 | Feb | 1 | 16.7% |
| Aus | AMID11 | Sales | 6 | Mar | 1 | 15.7% |
| Aus | AMID12 | Marketing | 12 | Jan | 0 | - |
| Aus | AMID12 | Marketing | 12 | Feb | 1 | 15.7% |
| Aus | AMID12 | Marketing | 12 | Mar | 1 | 16.7% |

It would be great if someone could help me get the desired result using Pandas. I tried Stacking/unstacking, but it's moving the other identifying columns

Comment: please add example actuall code instead of images..

Comment: I have made the edits @adirabargil

Comment: i ll try look onto it when o get home :)

Answer (score 0):

there is a little bit changes between the desired output to what i got but i think it is due to data being incorrect ('mar' and 'march' , and 'feb' twice):

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''Market LoanID  Segment LoanTerm    Field   FieldValue  Month
Aus AMID11  Sales   6   End AR  1   Jan
Aus AMID11  Sales   6   End AR  1   Feb
Aus AMID11  Sales   6   End AR  1   Mar
Aus AMID12  Marketing   12  End AR  0   Jan
Aus AMID12  Marketing   12  End AR  1   Feb
Aus AMID12  Marketing   12  End AR  1   March
Aus AMID11  Sales   6   IntRate 15.7%   Jan
Aus AMID11  Sales   6   IntRate 16.7%   Feb
Aus AMID11  Sales   6   IntRate 15.7%   March
Aus AMID12  Marketing   12  IntRate -   Jan
Aus AMID12  Marketing   12  IntRate 15.7%   Feb
Aus AMID12  Marketing   12  IntRate 16.7%   Feb'''),sep='\t')
indexes= ['Market','LoanID','Segment','LoanTerm','Month']
pd.pivot_table(data=df,index=indexes,columns='Field',values='FieldValue',aggfunc='first').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    Market  LoanID  Segment     LoanTerm    Month   End AR  IntRate
0   Aus     AMID11  Sales       6           Feb     1       16.7%
1   Aus     AMID11  Sales       6           Jan     1       15.7%
2   Aus     AMID11  Sales       6           Mar     1       NaN
3   Aus     AMID11  Sales       6           March   NaN     15.7%
4   Aus     AMID12  Marketing   12          Feb     1       15.7%
5   Aus     AMID12  Marketing   12          Jan     0       -
6   Aus     AMID12  Marketing   12          March   1       NaN
```